# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character') when trying to filter array data

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter, uisearchbar

I'm trying to "search" item from an array and if the item contains searchkey, it should appended the data to filteredArray. But when i'm trying to check if the data contains search key it showed an error "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character')"

Example:
let data: [String] = ["Apples", "Apricots", "Bananas", "Cherries", "Grapefruit", "Grapes"]
searchKey: "ap"
should filter "Apples" and "Appricots".
searcKey: "gr"
should filter "Grapefruit" and "Grapes".

My code:

```
let data: [String] = ["Apples", "Apricots", "Bananas", "Cherries", "Grapefruit", "Grapes"]
var filteredData: [String] = []

let searchKey: String = "Ap"

for item in data {
  if item.contains(searchKey) {
    filteredData.append(item)
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You should `import Foundation`

Answer (score 2):

Swift String [contains(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2893238-contains) accepts `Character` as parameter, instead of `String`:

```
func contains(_ element: Character) -> Bool
```

You can use Generic Instance Method [contains(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/3126753-contains) from `Foundation`:

```
func contains<T>(_ other: T) -> Bool where T : StringProtocol
```

Just by importing `Foundation` and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Seems your code works properly. You may need to import Foundation.
Also, there is a shorter way to filter your data:

```
let data: [String] = ["Apples", "Apricots", "Bananas", "Cherries", "Grapefruit", "Grapes"]
var filteredData: [String] = []
filteredData = data.filter({ $0.contains("Ap") })
```